# How to print index using values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below shows the values using indexes in array. How can I show the index using values?

```
class CrayonBox:

    def __init__(self):
        self.crayons=[]
        
    def add(self,crayon):
       return self.crayons.append(crayon)
       
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self.crayons[index]
        
    def __setitem__(self,index,value):
        self.crayons[index]=value

cb=CrayonBox()
cb.add("BLue")
cb.add("red")
print(cb[1])
print(cb[0])
cb[0]="yellow"
for item in cb:
      print(item)
```

Comment: define a method get index, and in it return index as `return self.cb.index(value)`

Comment: What if you have duplicate values in ```self.crayons``` ? What index would you expect ?

Comment: ```
for index, item in enumerate(cb):
    print(index, item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the index function.

Add this def to your class and try the following code:

```
def index(self, value):
        return self.crayons.index(value)

#CB inner list
self.crayons = ['yellow', 'red', 'blue']

## index of 'red' in cb

index = cb.index('red')
print('The index of red:', index)
```

The index method is an inbuilt method for a list datatype, so you wouldn't need  to define it when using it directly on an array/list. Since your object will not have this property by default, we've defined it in the CrayonBox class.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index)

Comment: This will throw a ```ValueError``` if ```red``` is not in the list.

Comment: I used red, since he included it in his example. After that it's up to him, whether he wants to implement some sort of exception handling or if he wants the code to stop.